# Installing Oozie in Ubuntu virtualbox

Tags: maven, ubuntu, virtualbox, oozie

This is the error that I am getting when I am trying to install oozie.

Hadoop - 2.5.1
Maven - 3.2.3
Oozie - 4.0.0

I am trying to install this in Virtualbox. I  have edited the pom.xml file as well. Is their a problem with the version of Hadoop and oozie?

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Oozie Main .................................. SUCCESS [  3.086 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Client ................................ SUCCESS [ 25.084 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.1.1.oozie-4.0.0 .............. SUCCESS [  1.705 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 1.1.1.oozie-4.0.0 ....... SUCCESS [  0.238 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.1.1.oozie-4.0.0 Test ......... SUCCESS [  0.517 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.2.0.oozie-4.0.0 .............. SUCCESS [01:41 min]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.2.0.oozie-4.0.0 Test ......... SUCCESS [ 35.359 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 2.2.0.oozie-4.0.0 ....... SUCCESS [  3.244 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 0.23.5.oozie-4.0.0 ............. SUCCESS [  5.024 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 0.23.5.oozie-4.0.0 Test ........ SUCCESS [  0.432 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 0.23.5.oozie-4.0.0 ...... SUCCESS [  0.275 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Libs ........................... SUCCESS [  3.906 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hbase 0.94.2.oozie-4.0.0 .............. SUCCESS [  0.763 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hbase Libs ............................ SUCCESS [  1.121 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog 0.5.0.oozie-4.0.0 ............ SUCCESS [  5.821 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog 0.6.0.oozie-4.0.0 ............ SUCCESS [ 26.194 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog Libs ......................... SUCCESS [  1.084 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Oozie ....................... FAILURE [ 10.767 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib HCatalog .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Core .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Docs .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Examples .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Tools ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie MiniOozie ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Distro ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:53 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-10-30T08:29:55+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 43M/105M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project oozie-sharelib-oozie: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib-oozie:jar:4.0.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.5.0.oozie-4.0.0, org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop-test:jar:2.5.0.oozie-4.0.0: Could not find artifact org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.5.0.oozie-4.0.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :oozie-sharelib-oozie
```

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this error while building oozie 4.0.1 in Hadoop 2.5.1. For this build, I have only changed hadoop versions in  `<OOZIE_BUILD_HOME>/pom.xml`
Then I changed the hadoop versions in the below folders and my error is resolved.

```
 <OOZIE_HOME>/hadooplibs/hadoop-2/pom.xml
 <OOZIE_HOME>/hadooplibs/hadoop-distcp-2/pom.xml
 <OOZIE_HOME>/hadooplibs/hadoop-test-2/pom.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 on dependencies issue. Try running the following before mvn at the oozie root.

```
find . -name pom.xml | xargs sed -ri 's/(2.2.0\-SNAPSHOT)/2.5.1/'
```